# .NET Identity not locking down static files after logging out

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I am building a .NET Core 3.1 Web Application using .NET Identity to secure some static files (these are documentation files generated automatically that I do not want general users to be able to see). The application also uses MVC to serve some administration pages.

Things appear to work OK (if a new visitor to the site tries to go to the static pages, they get redirected to the 'Access Denied' page). If one logs in (and has the 'Admin' role set in the AspNet database), one can then see these files.

**However**, after such a user logs out, one can *still* get to the protected static files (although one can no longer get to the Admin pages served using MVC). Here is how the system is set up in the *Startup.cs* file:

```
using CoreMVC.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using System.IO;

namespace CoreMVC
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            /*
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            */

            // This gets the [Authorize(Roles = "Admin")] decoration working. N.B. reset RequireConfirmedAccount to false
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
                .AddRoles<IdentityRole>()
                .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.AddControllersWithViews();
            services.AddRazorPages();

            // Try putting the fallback authorization policy here
            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.FallbackPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .RequireRole("Admin")
                    .Build();
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseDatabaseErrorPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            // Keep this in (otherwise we lose access to required resources)
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            // New mapping for static files - Seems OK to call UseStaticFiles twice!
            // Note: moved this after UseAuthentication and UseAuthorization
            // Try <host>/Documents/index.html
            app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
            {
                FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
                    Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "Documents")),
                RequestPath = "/Documents"
            });

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Note that the protection for the static files is provided by the fallback policy set up by the call to `services.AddAuthorization` in the `ConfigureServices` method, so this is distinct from the methods used to secure the pages served using MVC. I guess the problem is here somewhere.

I have tried deleting all Cookies using the browser dev tools but to no effect. Cookies on the system whilst logged in are:

```
.AspNetCore.Identity.Application
ARRAffinitySameSite
.AspNetCore.Antiforgery.9fXoN5jHCXs
ARRAffinity
```

After logging out, the *.AspNetCore.Identity.Application* cookie disappears. There do not seem to be any session or local variables stored.

Can anyone explain why this access is still being allowed and how to prevent it? As mentioned above, I suspect it is something to do with how the fallback policy is applied but I do not understand the details.

**Update**: On further investigation it seems that access to the static pages is only granted on the pages visited whilst logged in. This suggests that the server is maintaining some kind of list - an IIS issue maybe?

**Further update**: Thanks to the suggestion below, I now realise that this is due to browser caching, so not really an issue. I have now tried sticking

```
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="private, no-store" />
```

into the head section of the HTML pages and this seems to have worked.

Comment: Could this be browser caching? I can imagine there's a different caching policy for static files than for non-static.

Comment: Ah! That does seem to be the issue - thanks! I've not used .NET to serve static pages before, so I didn't think through how the browser might be behaving (Doh!)